# Batch file doesn't read flags correctly

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I've got a little batch file and it looks like this:

```
.\batchisp.exe –device at32uc3b1512 –hardware usb –operation erase f memory flash blankcheck loadbuffer G3Pro_USB.hex program verify start reset 0
```

The whole line is fine and works correctly if I run it straight in PowerShell. However, if I run the batch file, it runs this:

```
.\batchisp.exe ΓÇôdevice at32uc3b1512 ΓÇôhardware usb ΓÇôoperation erase f memory flash blankcheck loadbuffer G3Pro_USB.hex program verify start reset 0
```

Which does not work, because as you can see, the `-`'s have changed into `ΓÇô`'s... Can anybody tell me why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: Usually it has something to do with the encoding you used to save the batch script, like you used UTF-8 instead of ANSI or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `–` marks are not `-` characters. They are actually [endashes](http://unicode-table.com/en/2013/). These usually are caused by Word's [automatic en/emdashing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automatically-format-hyphens-as-en-dashes-and-em-dashes-8742DD30-AF01-464F-A8C8-EC6FDEE23197).

Powershell is smart enough to convert the endashes to dashes as "arguments", but cmd is not.

To fix this issue, replace `–` with `-`. A regex search/replace that catches all the alternative dash types that works in notepad++ is: `[–—‒]` to `-`.

Comment: This makes sense but what's the solution? I'm using N++ and it seems to interpret it incorrectly no matter what encoding I convert it to (i.e. ANSI, UTF-8, UTF-8-BOM, UCS-2 BE BOM, and UCS-2 LE BOM).

Comment: I've edited the answer to add a "fix", which is to just replace all the weird dashes with a normal dash.